# Error: Windows API error 5: Access is denied. when trying to add a local texmf tree to MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, texmf-local

I've created a local tree for my packages: `C:\Files\MikTex\localtexmf\tex\latex\sv` and copied the package files (including `svproc.cls`) there, refreshed the filename database, refreshed the font maps and updated the package database in `MiKTeX`.

It appears among the root paths:

```
"
`GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2019-07-05 17:29:21
MiKTeX: 2.9.7050
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 17763
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2019-07-05 07:49:55
LastUpdateAdmin: 2019-07-05 07:51:09
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no

Root0: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9

Root1: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9

Root2: C:\Files\MikTex\localtexmf

Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9

UserInstall: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: explorer`"
```

But when I try to compile my tex file I get the error:

```
"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Files/LaTeXFiles/authorLJP.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

! LaTeX Error: File `svproc.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
"
```

I closed TeXworks and MiKTeX.

When I opened MiKTeX again, the local tree was not listed there anymore...

A new try to add the local path resulted in the following error:

```
"
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2019-07-05 18:35:00
MiKTeX: 2.9.7050
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 17763
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: 2019-07-05 07:49:55
LastUpdateAdmin: 2019-07-05 07:51:09
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\Files\MikTex\localtexmf
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\prate\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: non-existing

ERROR DETAILS
Program: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console.exe
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winRegistry.cpp:173
Error: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.
Details: 
  path: Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\Core
"
```

Althought my local tree is listed, when I try to compile my tex file I get:

```
"! LaTeX Error: File `svproc.cls' not found."
```

Please help!

Comment: Thank you Azetina, for the editing my post and making it more readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, this issue can have three parts, I guess:

1. Did you install as admin MiKTeX, but added the `localtexfm` as user?
2. Do you have writing rights for your `localtexfm` directory: `C:\Files\MikTex\localtexmf`?
3. You have a broken MiKTeX installation.

Open MiKTeX Console as administrator and click on `Settings`. Then you should see something like that after clicking on `Directories`:

[image: miktex console]

Instead my `c:/localtexmf` you should see `C:\Files\MikTex\localtexmf`.

In the following you will see german Windows, I try to translate the relevant menu points, hopefully in the correct way ...

Now open the Windows Explorer, click on your directory `C:\Files\MikTex\localtexmf` (red arrow 1), right click on sub directory `tex` (red arrow 2) to get the context menu and choose `properties` to get the following window:

[image: properties]

Now click on `security` (red arrow 3) and select then àuthentified user` (red arrow 4) and check that you have only grey hooks at the position marked with red arrow 5.

I would guess you can have no reading rights on that directory and the following sub directories. If that is true, change the hook to the place I marked with red arrow 5 in the screenshot above.
If that is all correct and no changings are needed: okay, good.

Please reboot your computer (Windows is a OS which needs some reboots ...) and check if you still get the error message.

Now make sure that you have added all needed files for your package `sv` in your localtexmf. Is that package public? Do you have a link to it?

Now update your MiKTeX with the MiKTeX Console in admin mode! If you are lucky the update also repairs an wrong installation you possibly have (if the error message is still there).

Now reboot your computer (didn't I say that Windows likes reboots? :-( ).

Error gone?

Yes - Good!

No - Please contact the support for MiKTeX over the [MIKTeX homepage](http://https:miktex.org)