# MiKteX installed but won't load

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I am absolutely new to TeX.

I downloaded and installed TeXmaker, but after downloading MiKTeX onto my laptop (Windows 10) it  failed to load. It was from the `miktex.org` site.

So I repeated the process on a different laptop but got the same problem,

> Windows API error 5.

I uninstalled, tried different things, but I always get an error message (not always the same one).

Obviously I am doing something horribly wrong. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. MikTeX is a software distribution, with many different executable programs. Please clarify what you mean by MikTeX failing to load. Did you choose the default locations to install MikTeX, or did you choose a custom location? Did you user admin mode to install MikTeX? Which program, or programs, from the MikTeX distribution are failing to load? Did you download and install TeXmaker before or after installing MikTeX? Does TeXmaker fail to load completely, and/or is it unable to locate the MikTeX distribution and hence cannot be used to compile a LaTeX document?

Comment: On the last occasion I used a default location to install MiKteX, but on another occasion I had tried a custom location. I did not use admin mode to install it. I followed the instructions on https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex , i.e. for the basic MiKteX installer. TeXmaker was installed prior to this, and it seems to run.  After downloading the MiKteX installer, I go into my program files and click the executable document. That's when the errors appear.

Comment: Did you check MikTeX's log files to see which errors (if any) occurred during installation? I would definitely try installing MikTeX in admin mode.

Comment: I'll try admin mode thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install MiKTeX and an TeX Editor like TeXMaker on your computer is the following:

1. Download the **current** MiKTeX installer for your windows version from MiKTeX Homepage (I prefere to install the complete MiKTeX with netinstaller; If you install only Basic MiKTeX it could happen you have to install later missing packages depending on your used code).
2. Install MiKTeX on your computer (choose user or admin mode, I'm using admin mode).
3. Make sure the MiKTeX installation **terminated normaly**, then **Reboot** windows!
4. Download the **current** installer for your TeX Editor.
5. Install your TeX Editor. *The advantage in this order of installing is that your config program for your TeX Editor (if it can do it) is able to recognize the installed TeX distribution and to preconfig your TeX Editor proper.*
6. Test that the TeX Editor can compile a short TeX test file ...

Comment: I have since uninstalled Basic MiKteX 2.9.7100 Installer (64-bit). Then I uninstalled TeXmaker. Next step I re-downloaded Basic MiKteX. But then I received - An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winRegistry.cpp
  source line: 173
  message: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.
  info: path="Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.9\Core"

Comment: @argonaut did you a reboot after uninstallation? Does the uninstallation terminated normal?

Comment: I uninstalled normally, emptied my recycle bin and rebooted (again). I downloaded the program and ran the MiKteX setup wizard again. This time it says An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winRegistry.cpp
  source line: 183
  message: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.
  info: valueName="UserRoots"

Comment: Hm, have a look to my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498822/16550 perhaps you have no  writing  rules. If that does not help visit the MiKTeX Homepage and issue an bug report. Explain exactly what you did, which program you started, which OS you have and which log files you got ... And so not forget to mention, if you installed as admin or user and which pathes are used by the installer ...

Comment: Well, this is getting too complicated. I reported the installing error on the MiKTeX website (after joining a group) but the developer could not reproduce the error and offered no suggestions. So then I considered Texlive but my virus software warns that it is unsafe.Now I'm considering Wolfram Mathematica. All I want to do is typeset some equations into Word that look OK.

Comment: Update. My anti virus program (AVG) just sent me a message that install-tl-windows.exe (i.e. Texlive) is clean. It took them 2 days to check it. So I'll try Texlive