# pdftex not working, I dont know, ? Please help me

Tags: pdftex, miktex2.9

I used the miktex 2.8 version with an old pdflatex. And everything worked fine. I compiled my thesis of approximately 400 pages, with figures, texts, graphics in 3 or 4 minutes, no problem.

But I fall into the nonsense of upgrading miktex to 2.9
and everything stopped working.

A simple program takes hours to compile.
I can no longer produce the compilation of my thesis.
I've searched the internet, all possible tips to configure and already tried almost all. How can I set it up correctly ...
PLease Help...

Comment: From a Windows command prompt, what do you get if you type `pdflatex --version`?

Comment: MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7029 (1.40.20) (MiKTeX 2.9.7100 NEXT 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2018 Han The Thanh

Comment: This is version of PDFLATEX, which comes with MIKTEX

Comment: Well, MiKTeX 2.8 is rather old and on the homepage of MiKTeX is a remark that updating such old version can result in massive errors. That seems has happend to your system. I suggest to completly deinstall MiKTeX 2.8, reboot the computer, download the current installer from MiKTeX.com/downloads and install (best complete) MIkTeX 2.9.

Comment: Thanks for the indication, but unfortunately I have already done this process cleaned the entire installation of MIKTEX 2.8 and installed new version 64 bit update ...
But even so, he is in some process stopped, without finishing

Comment: I already upgraded, rebuilt the libraries and formats. It still doesn't work

Comment: Did you saw this answer of mine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500484/16550 ?

Comment: You wrote that since updating to and installing MikTeX2.9, "A simple program takes hours to compile". This is definitely not normal behavior. It also does not seem to be related to potential package incompatibilities your thesis document may be facing. Please edit your query to provide an example of a "simple program", and do tell us at which stage of the compilation process pdfLaTeX appears to get stuck.

Comment: If you have miktex 2.8 you probably should reinstall miktex completely instead of attempting to upgrade it, 2.8 is quite old and the miktex interface has changed quite a lot

Comment: Perhaps MiKTeX is simply installing missing packages.  What happens if you compile in some test folder a very simple hello-world document??

Comment: Do you have any news for us?